# Simulated Body fluid recipe

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, biochemistry

I'm working on preparing **SBF** in my school's lab however a couple of components are missing which are $\ce{NaHCO3}$ (0.350 g) and $\ce{K2HPO4}$ (0.228 g) .
Is it possible to replace these components with $\ce{NaCO3}$  and $\ce{KH2PO4}$ ?

The following link has the ions concentration of SBF:

https://www.irsm.cas.cz/materialy/cs_content/2002/Helebrant_CS_2002_0000.pdf

I'm not a chemist and I would really appreciate your view on this.

Comment: **No.** Or rather, you can do that, but your pH will be way off.

Comment: Probably not, sodium carbonate vs sodium bicarbonate are quite different (likewise for the phosphorous containing compounds). It *looks* like its setting up some kind of buffer, so changing things won't really work. You *could* just try it **but** all of the chemicals listed are really, really inexpensive and readily available- just buy what you need

Comment: @NotEvans. Thanks...Is there another way to prepare SBF without the chemicals I'm missing? Another recipe :)?

Comment: I couldn't say, its very much not my area of chemistry. Google is likely your best bet (but as I say, just buy new chemicals, they're cheap... $\ce{NaHCO3}$ especially, you can find it in the baking aisle of your local supermarket...